# How to display additional (calculated) entity field into dynamic data web site?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm displaying list of products using dynamic data web site. That is easy.

Is there any way to display amount of 'orders' related to that product? How to do that?

Thanks.

P.S. Probably, I should write a stored procedure for that and work with SP as with table?

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Product
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    public int orderNum
    {
        get
        {   
            return //Insert code here to get number of ordrs for product
        }
    }
    }


public class ProductMetadata
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Display(Name = "[Number of Orders]", AutoGenerateField = true, AutoGenerateFilter = false)]
    public object orderNum { get; set; } 

        .
        .
        .

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to extend the class generated for the table; extending the class you can define custom field and in such a field you can calculate (by code using, for example, Linq) the desired total using as parameter the other field of the record.